# What is the coefficient of friction of a gecko's foot?

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

Since geckos can hang from a vertical wall, does that mean the coefficient of friction is $\mu=\infty$? If not, how would one calculate it? And is coefficient of friction relevant to something that can climb across a ceiling, like a fly, for example?

Comment: How geckos climb on just about anything goes far beyond simple friction concepts. Check out this site: https://www.livescience.com/47307-how-geckos-stick-and-unstick-feet.html#:~:text=Geckos%20can%20stick%20to%20surfaces,tiny%20microscopic%20hairs%20called%20setae.&text=Scientists%20already%20knew%20that%20the,der%20Waals%20force%20kicks%20in.

Comment: No single thing has a distinct coefficient of friction. The coefficient of friction always is measured between two surfaces. (E.g., what's the coefficient of friction of a gecko's foot and a pane of window glass?)

Comment: The simple notion of a "coefficient of friction" only really applies to the Coulomb model of friction. Since this is the only model described in non-specialist books on the subject (because it is simple to understand and use without computer modelling) it is easy to get the wrong idea that it is a "law of physics" when it isn't. It is irrelevant for understanding geckos. (In fact it's not even very relevant for understanding inanimate objects like car tyres, or highly polished metal surfaces in contact with each other).

Comment: See; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko#Adhesion_ability